# ssd_kerasの学習データはどれですか

Tags: python, keras

sad_kerasの学習データのデータ件数とそのデータが見たいのですが、
どれに当たるのかわかりません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSDのトレーニングに用いられるデータセットで有名なものに[PASCAL VOC](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/)や[MSCOCO](http://cocodataset.org/)があります。

尚、OSSでSSDのKeras実装はたくさんあります（[これ](https://github.com/rykov8/ssd_keras)や[これ](https://github.com/pierluigiferrari/ssd_keras)など）が、これらはSSDの論文の実装（[Caffe版](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd)）で作られた重みをKeras版に変換して使っていることが多いです。変換については[ここ](https://github.com/pierluigiferrari/caffe_weight_converter)で詳しく紹介されています。

Comment: 教えていただきありがとうございます！